# Java - Batch Processing

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-batch

I'm trying to generate a CSV file based on a list of objects returned by a web service method.

The problem is that I want to retrieve all of the objects available, but the call will **'fail'** if I try to get **more than 100 entries** (the method has 2 parameters which give me the possibility to specify the interval of objects I want to retrieve, *ex: from 10 to 50, from 45 to 120, etc.*).

I thought of making *sequential calls* while incrementing the two indexes which represent the interval, but someone suggested that I should use *batch processing* for this. As far as I searched the internet I only found examples on how to export database data or xml files into csv, using Spring Batch.

Could someone explain me how should I handle this situation? Or at least point me to an example/tutorial similar to what I need? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you try to load all data from a single request through a webservice , you are exposed to get a memory or timeout exception because data too much large in response, maybe you should try make some calls to your webservice, something like a paginated request, after each response you can insert response in your local database.

When all calls are over, call a process and build your csv file.

regards.